# iOS Custom UIActivityItemProvider share image and text

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, share

I'va subclassed UIActivityItemProvider to be able to choose what to share if the user choose Facebook or Twitter or Mail etc.
But I can only share text OR image in the function - (id)item, I don't know how to share both text and image for example.

If I read tutorials I know how to do for all share options, but I don't want all share option to have an image or a link or text :

```
    NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText, [NSURL URLWithString:url], image];
    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                      applicationActivities:nil];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it

```
CustomActivityItemProvider *itemProvider = [[CustomActivityItemProvider alloc] init];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[itemProvider, image]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
```

This will use my CustomActivityItemProvider where I choose the text and the image will be used if the share option choosed is compatible (facebook, twitter etc)